# Xcode Git Submodule Commit Issue

Tags: xcode, git, commit, git-submodules

**What I did**

- I made a new Single Page App project in my application called "parent".
- I made a new Static library project called "child" and I've Added it as a git submodule in my parent project folder.
- I have imported the child project into the parent project by dragging from the finder from submodule directory, the child project file  to my parent project in Xcode window -> Parent Project file tree.

**Now Is my problem**

- When I would like to do a commit through File -> Source Control -> Commit, I select files enter my message and do a commit all goes right.
- Now When I make a change into my child project and try to commit by the same way, xcode make me know it success the commit
- Now try a pull from File -> Source Control -> Pull, My child project is selectable but my parent project has "Uncommited Changes".
- So I come back to the commit interface and I saw the items that should have been committed during the last commit. Especially the folder of my submodule project.

**What I did to resolve the problem**

I use git from the command line in my parent project folder:
git add .
git commit -am "Core has been modified"

When I use this, I can access my to repository from the pull interface, that confirm that all change has been committed.

**The real Problem**

My company would like to make that work only with the Xcode SCM tool.
The problem seems to be linked to the use of "Submodule"
How can I make it work without the use of the Command Line

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem. It's like a small bug in XCode. Our workaround at the moment is the same as you mentioned and the only solution would be a bugfix or enhancement how XCode support

Our workflow looks like the following :

-commit submodule changes with XCode 
-commit main changes with XCode
-commit main directory change with CLI ( git commit ) 
-push main & submodule with XCode

we hope that this small bug would be fixed in the future directly in XCode

Answer (score 1):

When you make a commit in a submodule, it shows up as a change in the parent.

The solution is to make changes to the submodule first, then commit the changes to the parent.  This way all of your changes to the submodule will get bundled into the parent project commit.

Comment: Could you give me a more concise procedure to achieve that?

Comment: It seems you already know how to commit changes, all I'm saying here is (1) commit changes in the submodule first (2) then commit changes in the parent repository.  I don't know how to make it any more concise.  From your description, it sounds like you know how to do it the other way around.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake... less concise

Comment: When I do your procedure it work the same way. Xcode say that the source has been commited but when I go back to the commit interface, they still here. Maybe I missed a step. How do you update your submodule?

Comment: In what interface do you make your commit?